# Slide page content when slide menu appear WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Guys!
I create page in WPF and add some menu, which slides from the right side of my page when I push a button. Is it possible to slide all my content to right side too when menu is apears? Will be grateful for any solutions.

Comment: You have tried what?

Comment: Just want to move all page content to right side when click on button menu. The aim is to do menu like android apps have.